# Cannot use the "over" clause with MySQL workbench 8.0 (MySQL version 5.7.31)

Tags: mysql, group-by, mysql-workbench, windowing, over-clause

I struggle to see what I'm doing wrong.  I have noticed that some syntax doesn't work (I've had this issue with the keywords "WITH" and now with "OVER".

I am applying a windowing function on a table with the columns `id`, `price` and `cluster`.  I want to select the maximum price of a cluster.  Here I use the "max" function as a toy example.  (What I really want is the price with the greatest `id` for all `cluster` values.)

```sql
select max(price) over (cluster) as last_p
from transactions tx
right join tx_ids as ids ON ids.ids=tx.id
group by cluster
order by cluster;
```

I suspect the issue is with my version of workbench or mysql but haven't found much yet while searching for my problem online.

[image: Simple windowing (analytic) MySQL application]

Comment: Window function exist on in the mysql server 8.x Workbench is only a gui

Comment: MySql 5.7 does not support window functions. If it did, you would need to specify a [valid `over` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html). `over(columnname)` is not valid.

Comment: What does `select version()` gives you when you run it?

Comment: @GMB It returns the value "5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1"

Comment: @GSerg, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @GSerg, the windowing is not supported on MySQL 5.7.

It was introduced on MySQL 8.
Ref: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4193269